# Android java toggle headset

Tags: java, android, headset

I want to play the sound of my android lollipop device over the speakers while my headset is connected.

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
audioManager.setWiredHeadsetOn(false);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

When I use this code, the device sound will play over my speakers while the headset is connected. This is exactly what I want but the problem is, that when I use this code and I try to change the volume, my device changes the call volume and not the media volume as usual.

I hope you can understand by bad english. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well it's changing the call volume because you turned speakerphone on.

Comment: But when I make this: "audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);" the audio will play over the headset.

Comment: Well I would avoid not forcing audio feedback on the speakerphone unless it's an actual telephony app. It's bad practice, users likely wouldn't appreciate it and it's not suggested in the API guidelines. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setSpeakerphoneOn%28boolean%29

Comment: That being said, you might want to look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html